# How can I convert an object name to a character object

Tags: r, eval

I have a function, that just do a print, `mytable` is a global variable

```
f <- function(field){ print(mytable[mytable$a == field,]) }
```

My problem is that this function is called (not by me, it is sent as command to R by another process like an editor) as `f(EXAMPLE)`, `f(EXAMPLE2)`... this fails because `EXAMPLE` is not a defined variable, I would like `EXAMPLE` to be `"EXAMPLE"` (a string).

What can I do in the function `f` for `field` to have the value "EXAMPLE" when `f(EXAMPLE)` is evaluated ?

I realize that this is very convoluted...

Comment: I would begin by choosing another name for variable `table`!!

Comment: Just to be clear ... you are NOT evaluating. Evaluation would recover the value of the object in the nearest enclosing environment (quite possibly not the `globalenv()` ) that has the name 'EXAMPLE'. You are acting on a formal argument to convert its name to a character object.

Comment: I edited the title, thanks I was unclear about how to phrase the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `deparse(substitute(yourobject))` :

```
R> deparse(substitute(foo))
[1] "foo"
```